# How can I change the starting and ending items of an array while following the same order?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I would like to sort the array

```
order = ['B', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'C', 'F']
```

in a way that would return

```
['F', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'C']
```

In other words, the last element of `order` should be moved to the beginning and all other elements should be shifted right one position.

A new array is to be returned (`order` is not to be modified). How can I do that?

Comment: IOW you want to rotate the array?

Comment: Yes, did not know Ruby had a method to do that. Thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is go through [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html)’s instance methods, looking for one that does the job. Had you done that you would have found `rotate`. (Had that failed, look through the `Enumerable` module.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your return values are subsequent outputs you can use the `rotate` method:

```
order.rotate(-1)
```